# Pass UIPickerView row index through closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

My goal is to pass the rowClosure to the other view controller, but I just stuck at here. Anything I should do to solve it??

ViewController1

```
var rowClosure : (Int) -> (Int) = { x in return x}

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    self.rowClosure(row)

    }
```

ViewController2

```
let vc1 = ViewController1()
    var row: Int!
row = vc1.rowClosure
```

But, it's not working

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `ViewController1 `, your closure doesn't have any value also, cant tell how your code work, post more related code would help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use closure, you code should look something like this:

VC1

```
var rowClosure : ((Int) -> Void)?

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    self.rowClosure?(row)

    }
```

Then in VC2, you get a reference to VC1 and set a closure with code that needs to get executed in VC2 when you call closure from VC1:

```
vc1.rowClosure = { (vc1Row) in
    //do something with row, for example
    vc2.row = vc1Row
}
```